# Tensorflow Keras: ValueError: Found unexpected losses or metrics that do not correspond to any Model output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a model that was built using keras Sub Classing API which looks as follows:

```py
class APR(keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(APR, self).__init__()
    # layers for bidirectional
    forward_layer = keras.layers.GRU(
      128, return_sequences=True, dropout=.5,
      name="gru_forward_layer"
    )
    backward_layer = keras.layers.LSTM(
      128, return_sequences=True, dropout=.5,
      go_backwards=True, name="lstm_backward_layer"
    )
    self.embedding = keras.layers.Embedding(
          vocab_size, 100, 
          input_length=max_words,
          weights=[embedding_matrix], 
          trainable=True,
          name = "embedding_layer"
    )
    self.bidirectional = keras.layers.Bidirectional(
        forward_layer,
        backward_layer = backward_layer,
        name= "bidirectional_layer"
    )
    self.gru_layer = keras.layers.GRU(
              512, return_sequences=True,
              dropout=.5,
              name= "gru_layer"
      )
    self.lstm_layer = keras.layers.LSTM(
              512, return_sequences=True,
              dropout=.5,
              name="lstm_layer"
    )
    self.fc_1 = keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu", name="upvote_fc1")
    self.pooling_layer = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(
          name="average_pooling_layer"
    )
    self.concatenate_layer = keras.layers.Concatenate(name="concatenate_layer_layer")

    self.dense_1 = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name="dense_1")
    self.dropout_1 = keras.layers.Dropout(rate= .5, name="dropout_layer_0")
    self.dense_2 = keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', name="dense_2")
    self.dropout_2 =  keras.layers.Dropout(rate= .5, name="dropout_layer_1")
    self.dense_3 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name="dense_3")
    self.dropout_3 = keras.layers.Dropout(rate= .5, name="dropout_layer_2")
    self.rating_output = keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax', name="rating_output")
    self.recommend_output = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name="recommend_output")
        
  def call(self, inputs):
    text, upvote = inputs
    # Leaning the text features
    x_1 = self.embedding(text)
    x_1 = self.bidirectional(x_1)
    x_1 = self.gru_layer(x_1)
    x_1 = self.lstm_layer(x_1)
    x_1 = self.pooling_layer(x_1)

    # Learning the upvotes
    x_2 = self.fc_1(upvote)

    # concatenation
    x = self.concatenate_layer([x_1, x_2])

    # leaning combinned features
    x = self.dense_1(self.dropout_1(x))
    x = self.dense_2(self.dropout_2(x))
    x = self.dense_3(self.dropout_3(x))

    # outputs
    rating = self.rating_output(x)
    recommend = self.recommend_output(x)
    return rating, recommend
```

Here's how i'm creating an instance of this model.

```py
apr_model = APR()
apr_model.build([(None, 100), (None, 1)])
apr_model.summary()
```

I'm then compiling the model as follows:

```py
apr_model.compile(
    loss = {
        "recommend_output" : keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
        "rating_output" : keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
    },
    metrics = ['accuracy'],
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
)
```

The problem comes when I'm trying to run the training loop which look as follows:

```py
BATCH_SIZE = 128


recommend_output_early_stoping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='recommend_output_loss',
    min_delta=0,
    patience=5,
    verbose=1,
    mode='auto',
    baseline=None,
    restore_best_weights=False,
)
rating_output_early_stoping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='rating_output_loss',
    min_delta=0,
    patience=5,
    verbose=1,
    mode='auto',
    baseline=None,
    restore_best_weights=False,
)


history = apr_model.fit(
    x = [train_tokens_sequence_padded, train_up_votes_scaled], 
    y = [train_recommends.astype('int32'), train_ratings],
    epochs = 10,
    verbose = 1,
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size= BATCH_SIZE,
    validation_data=([val_tokens_sequence_padded, val_up_votes_scaled], [val_recommends.astype('int32'), val_ratings]),
    validation_batch_size = BATCH_SIZE//2,
    # callbacks =[recommend_output_early_stoping, rating_output_early_stoping]
)
```

I'm getting the error which says:

```sh
ValueError: Found unexpected losses or metrics that do not correspond to any Model output: dict_keys(['recommend_output', 'rating_output']). Valid mode output names: ['output_1', 'output_2']. Received struct is: {'recommend_output': <keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy object at 0x7f5f08ce69d0>, 'rating_output': <keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x7f5f08ce6990>}.
```

What may be possibly the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Changing this:

```py
apr_model.compile(
    loss = {
        "recommend_output" : keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
        "rating_output" : keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
    },
    metrics = ['accuracy'],
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
)
```

To this:

```py
apr_model.compile(
    loss = {
        "output_2" : keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
        "output_1" : keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
    },
    metrics = ['accuracy'],
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
)
```

Fixes my problem